# How to download stock data from Matlab

Tags: matlab, download, stock

I have downloaded the last version I found (18/04/2017) of hist_stock_data.

It does not get the data from Yahoo (returning zero status).

Any way to fix this?

Any alternative for downloading stock data from Matlab?

Comment: Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the fetch function?

```
d = fetch(c,s) returns data for all fields from the Yahoo! website for the indicated security.
```

**Note**:  This function does not support retrieving multiple securities at once. You must fetch a single security at a time.